# With PHP how pass data to html page?

Tags: php, database, post, encryption, telegram

Guys i'm creating a **bot** on a telegram that at certain (textual) input responds by writing in various ways.
The bot is also able to create buttons in the telegram chat (between the user and the bot).

In one of these buttons, if the user clicks, a page from my website opens.

I have to switch the chat ID to this internet page but I'm looking for a safe way to do it.

I could put the id in the link

```
example.com?chat_id=xxx
```

but it's unsafe and I don't want the user to be able to change the link and the value of the **chat_id**
So how could I do?
Is there a way to pass the data to the internet page from file.php?

In short, a `POST` method

I hope you can help me (sorry for my English)

Comment: "...but it's unsafe..." How is it unsafe?

Comment: So your telling me "chat_id" is a vulnerable variable that you dont want the client to be able to change? From what im reading here, it sounds like you want to pass that variable to the client first to then pass it to the server (which makes it so the user can change it, even if its $_POST or whatever).

Comment: @James k Polik Is unsafe because user can change the URL (so the id) and to use an id of other user. How can i do?

Comment: @keanu-reeves yes is vulnerable and i want to pass it to this page of my website. In this way i’m sure the page is open by the user clicked on link in telegram and i’m sure he can’t to change chat_id

Comment: As I said, it sounds like you want to pass that variable to the client first, which makes it so the user is able to change it. Post, get and all of those other methods can be altered. I suggest you create some kind of login page that links that chat_id to your telegram account which could then create a super secret token, for example. That token would then be stored as a session variable.

Comment: As a low-security simple workaround you can have your PHP page generate a 12 byte random token using `random_bytes(12)`, then internally map this to the actual chat id. Base64-encode the random bytes into 16 chars and use that as the chat id in the link. For anything higher security you'll have to authenticate the user.

Comment: @keanu-reeves what do you mean with “login page that links that chat_id to your telegram” ?

Answer (score 1):

When you get "chat_id", you can get user id too.

> **users.getUsers**
>   Returns basic user info according to their identifiers.

1. You need to create a key, for your bot. Use the same in your php
   application. Make a hash with infos and your key.
2. Replace example.com?chat_id=xxx with
   example.com?chat_id=YOUR HASH.When the user go to your page, decrypt them with your key.
   And now, you have chat id & user.

**I recommend to use a salt**

Comment: Is an incredible idea ! I have only two doubts: 1) getUsers what return ? Do you have a link of telegrap API about this method ? can i use getUsers also for channel or group? 2) In Php are there method to do a hash ?

Comment: You can be check at this link, what this method return: https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getUsers , for channel & groups too. The best function for me to hash your data it's BCRYPT https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.password-hash.php ;)

Comment: yes but if i use password_hash(chat_id, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) i have not a key. This function doesn't use a key...no ?

Comment: I have a sample in my github ;) https://github.com/lemoinemeddy/bcryptphp/blob/master/permission.php

Comment: plase can you write an example here editing your answer ? Please is really difficult for me :/

Comment: In first,your bot needed to get the hash, for generate a url for user.
For this ,he need to get the bcrypt hash from your php application.
He asked with a salt, and your key, and datas, hashed in sha1 for example.
sha1(salt|key|datas);
In second, your php application decrypt this, and compare if you salt and key has correct, and get the datas.
Your php application return the hash in bcrypt format, at your bot.
password_hash("mydatas|mykey|salt", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
By this way, it's moore secure. no use sha1 function for user url.

Comment: Can you show me code? Know i understand how do an hash (using password_hash function) but not how to do an hash with a key

Comment: the key can be anything, in variable.  $key = "thismykey"; $key= "otherkey44567"; etc...

Comment: new sample for you https://github.com/lemoinemeddy/bcryptphp/blob/master/bcryptbase.php